# What are the advantages and disadvantages of union-find and breadth first search?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search, union-find

What are the advantages and disadvantages of union-find and breadth first search?
example: theoretical algorithm complexity, application differences, and so on.

Comment: You can easily find in any standard algorithms book or even search with exact text in your question you will get ton of results on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that these are two separate questions.

**Union-Find**

*Theoretical Algorithm Complexity*

The complexity of Union-Find is O(logn) when path compression is used and is O(n) if it is not used. A rigorous proof of this may be more than what you were looking for, but they can be found on the internet.

*Applications*

Union-Find is used in Kruskal's algorithm to find a minimum spanning tree. The union-find algorithm is used to keep track of the disjoint minimum spanning trees (equivalence classes) formed through the intermediate steps of Kruskal's. This is my only encounter with the algorithm. Other applications can be found on the internet such as the following.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure#Applications

**Breadth First Search**

*Theoretical Algorithm Complexity*

The time complexity of BFS is O(V + E) where V is the number of vertices and E is the number of edges. For complete graphs, the time complexity can be thought of as O(V^2). For sparse graphs, the time complexity can be thought of as O(V). The time complexity comes from the fact that every vertex is explored only once and every edge is explored twice at the worst in an undirected graph (or once in a directed graph).

*Applications*

My encounters with BFS have been in places such as finding the minimum spanning tree of an unweighted graph, finding the shortest path to a node in an unweighted graph (BFS does not work for weighted graphs where the shortest path is not equal to the minimum number of edges between them). Another use for BFS is level-order traversal of a tree. Many more examples of applications can be found here:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/applications-of-breadth-first-traversal/